# C# WIA Automatic Document Feeder giving grey on sides

Tags: c#, .net, scanning, wia

The problem I'm facing is that when I scan a A4 size page with a WIA based C# windows form application, the scanned image has grey on the sides. The scanner is automatic document feeder. Any help in this regard will be helpful?

[image: The scanned image I am getting]

```
private void SetupPageSize(Device wia, bool rotatePage, PageSize pageSize, int DPI, WIA.Item item)
    {

        //Setup Page Size Property
        foreach (WIA.Property itemProperty in item.Properties)
        {

            if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Horizontal Resolution"))
            {
                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(DPI);
            }
            else if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Vertical Resolution"))
            {
                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(DPI);
            }
            else if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Horizontal Extent"))
            {

                double extent = DPI * pageSize.Height;

                if (rotatePage)
                {
                    extent = DPI * pageSize.Width;
                }
                //extent = 1250;
                //extent = 1230;


                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(extent);


            }
            else if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Vertical Extent"))
            {
                double extent = DPI * pageSize.Width;

                if (rotatePage)
                {
                    extent = pageSize.Height * DPI;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("vertical extent:" + extent);
                //extent = extent + 500;
                //extent = 1750;

                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(extent);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Post some code please, or are you questioning a downloaded application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paper sheet is not aligned in the feeder.

Comment: the feeder has adjustments for a4 size paper and a5 size paper, the scanning utility that comes with the hp scanner does a fine job with the scanning process.

Comment: The scanning utility performs some analysis and cuts the image.

Comment: Not really a coding solution man, but it made me laugh a little. :) (PS. this seems more like a comment than an answer)

Comment: should have posted some code my bad, was not sure what was relevant here.

Comment: @afnan1992 You need to find property named like `ScannerPictureAutoDeskew` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630196(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @afnan1992 Try code from here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/792316/WIA-Scanner-in-Csharp-Windows-Forms and if it works try to set `ScannerPictureAutoDeskew` of WIA Item to 0 (is WIA_AUTO_DESKEW_ON)

Comment: @afnan1992 Or try this library (you can download it at "Source code" tab) https://scanwia.codeplex.com.